# Uploading files via php in drupal

Tags: php, file-upload, drupal-7

I am trying to get the user to upload a file and then save the file to the server using php. My code works on a non-drupal website but not on drupal. Here is my code:

```
<?php
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
?>
```

On my non drupal site, I just create a folder called upload in the root directory and the files save to it no problem. In drupal, I created an upload folder in the sites/default/files/ directory and i can't find the file. The default is the file is supposed to be saved in the root folder but i can't find it, do you know where the file is being saved? Thanks.

Comment: it would be uploaded to the same directory that the script is being initialized from. alternatively, you can set the full path in move_uploaded_files so that they always end up where you want.. i am praying that you are doing some sort of checking to ensure that users aren't uploading malicious files though.

Comment: how can i set the full path? wouldn't i have to know the root folder location and then navigate to where i want the file stored. This code is written in one of the Basic Page content types so i don't know where the script is being initialized from since drupal doesn't have a separate file for each page.

Comment: echo getcwd(); will give you the current working directory you are in.

Comment: getcwd() is showing the correct directory but it is still not saving the file. Do you think it has anything to do with htcaccess or any other permission?